# How to check selected text in multi line text Box in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, select, textbox

I have two Multi-Line Text Boxes and one arrow button in my application and what I want is that when a user selects any one or many lines from Multi-Line textbox 1 ,it should update the status of that line from 0 to 1 and then I want to load the rows whose status is 1 into Multi-Line textbox 2.I have tried but didn't know what should I do next?

**Code**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < txtNewURLs.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (txtNewURLs.Lines[i].Select)
    {

    }
}
```

Can any body please help me or give some suggession to do this task?

Comment: you can use list box in this scenario

Comment: is your 0 and 1 only virtual to better explain what you want or do you have a variable that should be set to 0 and 1 for each line?

Comment: This is where a SelectionChanged even would be handy, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist for a textbox. You could create a custom control to do this, though.

Comment: Try it using a list box control, I think (like Arshad) that it can be done with it. Good luck.

Comment: ya thats ok but how user can add new entry as we can enter new entry in text box but not in list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Multiline TextBox similar to MSDNS's [How to: Create a Multiline TextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742157.aspx), you can utilize the [SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext.aspx) property to retrieve the text that the user has selected. The lines will be separated by `\r\n`

i.e.

If I have the below (inbetween the page lines):

---

test0

test1

---

And I selected lines `test0` and `test1`, then `SelectedText` would be `test0\r\ntest1`.

You could then split on the `\r\n` and retrieve each selected line.

```
// Retrieve selected lines
List<string> SelectedLines = Regex.Split(txtNewURLs.SelectedText, @"\r\n").ToList();
// Check for nothing, Regex.Split returns empty string when no text is inputted
if(SelectedLines.Count == 1) {
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SelectedLines[0])) {
        SelectedLines.Remove("");
    }
}

// Retrieve all lines from textbox
List<string> AllLines = Regex.Split(txtNewURLs.Text, @"\r\n").ToList();
// Check for nothing, Regex.Split returns empty string when no text is inputted
if(AllLines.Count == 1) {
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AllLines[0])) {
        AllLines.Remove("");
    }
}

string SelectedMessage = "The following lines have been selected";
int numSelected = 0;
// Find all selected lines
foreach(string IndividualLine in AllLines) {
    if(SelectedLines.Any(a=>a.Equals(IndividualLine))) {
        SelectedMessage += "\nLine #" + AllLines.FindIndex(a => a.Equals(IndividualLine));
        // Assuming you store each line status in an List, change status to 1
        LineStatus[AllLines.FindIndex(a => a.Equals(IndividualLine));] = 1;
       numSelected++;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show((numSelected > 0) ? SelectedMessage : "No lines selected.");
```

Comment: I Just comment this line                                             // LineStatus[AllLines.FindIndex(a => a.Equals(IndividualLine));] = 1;   and I changed its status from database to 1 from 0.  thanks bob it solve my current issue